# MYSQLI rows calculate is too slow

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, count, rows

I am trying to calculate the visitors on my table with SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with MYSQLI but it's slow .It's over 15 seconds.What can i do make it faster ?
I have to mention that my table is MyISAM and has in total over 2 million rows.

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *  FROM visitors_table WHERE visitor_affiliate= 'first user'")) {
    /* determine number of rows result set */

     $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

    /* close result set */
    $result->close();
}


 if ($result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *  FROM visitors_table WHERE visitor_affiliate= 'seconduser'")) {
        /* determine number of rows result set */

         $row_cnt2 = $result2->num_rows;

        printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt2);

        /* close result set */
        $result2->close();
    }

 if ($result3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *  FROM visitors_table WHERE visitor_affiliate= 'thirduser'")) {
        /* determine number of rows result set */

         $row_cnt3 = $result3->num_rows;

        printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt3);

        /* close result set */
        $result2->close();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated ..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @anantkumarsingh SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is not a column

Comment: Yikes! MyISAM and 2M rows is painful. Is your `visitors_table` column an index of some sort?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh That's a [MySQL Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Comment: @Machavity i have a column ID that is auto increment … i have also checked  SELECT ID   . but it's too slow also...

Comment: sorry . it skipped from my mind that time. thanks. try like `SELECT COUNT(*)` and check

Comment: @jason88 Have you tried running an `EXPLAIN` on the query?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I have also tried SELECT COUNT(*) but is too slow also...

Comment: @Machavity Could you help me? How can i use EXPLAIN? I really don't know

Comment: @jason88 Here you go [EXPLAIN explained](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)

Comment: Try create an index on visitors_table(visitor_affiliate) and use a group by to retrieve three counts in one query.

Comment: @Machavity  I am checking how EXPLAIN working..Thanks

Comment: @Tim3880 I have already have an index …but how can i use one query only to retrieve three counts?

Comment: Are you sure you have an index on this particular column?  The index on auto increment column can not be used for your query.

Comment: @Tim3880 Ok..if i set an index on visitor_affiliate will this speed up the process?

Comment: I guess the query should be done in 1 or two seconds, if you can do the 3 queries without index in 15 seconds. No promise,  however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make you sure have an index on the column visitor_affiliate:

```
CREATE INDEX aff_index ON visitors_table(visitor_affiliate) ;
```

Then you need one query to get the three results:

```
SELECT visitor_affiliate, COUNT(*) AS tot FROM visitors_table 
 WHERE visitor_affiliate IN ( 'firstuser',  'seconduser',  'thirduser')
 GROUP BY visitor_affiliate
```

It's usually faster than three queries.

If you still need separated queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot FROM visitors_table 
WHERE visitor_affiliate IN = 'firstuser'
```

Comment: I made the index …how can i get the the number after the query for every user?

Comment: SELECT  COUNT(*) AS tot FROM visitors_table='Name'

Comment: Hi Tim .. I can't understand..could give me an example with php in the already example i have above?Thanks.. and sorry for asking so  many questions